# Select all values from 2 tables

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables code first, `A` and `B` and a join table (one to many relationship to link `A` and `B`), I would like to get all the results, not duplicate of the tables `A` and `B` and return it as selectList:

```
var a = from s in db.A
    join ss in db.B on s.ps_id equals ss.ss_id
    orderby s.ps_label
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = s.ps_id.ToString(),
        Value = s.ps_label
    };

return a;
```

This only returns results from the `A` table, but not from `B` as well. What is wrong, and what is your advice for best practice and performance for this?

Comment: Well, your `select` doesn't include any properties from `ss`, which is the only way you would be able to return any elements from table B. 

Also, if it's one-to-many, then why do you mention that there's three tables, including a join table, but this third table is never referenced in the code?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "not duplicate of the tables"?

Comment: what I mean "not duplicate..." means the results got from query should contains no duplication. Also there third table is just a junction table to reference relationship of  table A to table B, with only their ids, actually when I import the table as code first in the solution asp.net mvc, those tables are not imported

Comment: It would be helpful to see the class definitions for `A` and `B`, and to know where results from `B` fit into this selectList thing since `SelectListItem` doesn't include anything from `B`.